# EC2 instance creation

Tags: amazon-web-services, terraform, terraform-provider-aws

I'm trying to create multiple EC2 instance but they have different AMIs, instance types and should be in different availability zones as shown below. I've tried a few different ways but can't make it work.

```
locals {
  az_ami = [
    {Name = "host1", type = "t3a.medium", az = "eu_west_2a", ami_id = "ami-01234abc"},
    {Name = "host2", type = "t3a.micro", az = "eu_west_2b", ami_id = "ami-01234def"},
    {Name = "host3", type = "t3a.medium", az = "eu_west_2b", ami_id = "ami-01234gef"},
    {Name = "host4", type = "t3a.medium", az = "eu_west_2a", ami_id = "ami-01234hty"}
  ]
}

#variable "ami_id" {}

resource "aws_instance" "myinstance" {
  count    = length(local.az_ami)
  for_each = [{ for i in local.az_ami: }]

  dynamic "ec2_instance"{
    for_each = local.az_ami[count.index]
    content {
      instance_type     = "ec2_instance.value.Name"
      availability_zone = "ec2_instance.value.az"
      ami               = "ec2_instance.value.ami_id"
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: It looks somewhat(not extact match) similar to [this](https://devops.stackexchange.com/questions/2749/how-to-apply-using-terraform-to-launch-multiple-ec2-resource-with-different-conf)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to use `count`, then it should be:

```
resource "aws_instance" "myinstance" {

  count             = length(local.az_ami)

  instance_type     = local.az_ami[count.index].type
  availability_zone = local.az_ami[count.index].az
  ami               = local.az_ami[count.index].ami_id
  
  tags = {
    Name = local.az_ami[count.index].Name
  }
}
```

But with `for_each` it could be:

```
resource "aws_instance" "myinstance2" {

  for_each    = {for idx, val in local.az_ami: idx => val}

  instance_type     = each.value.type
  availability_zone = each.value.az
  ami               = each.value.ami_id
  
  tags = {
    Name = each.value.Name
  }
}
```

Comment: the fact that terraform still cannot simply for_each over an array... :facepalm:

Comment: @luk2302 Yes, something that seems so natural  to have is missing.